# A question regarding to the state maintainance

Tags: iphone

If i have   total 10 views  such as  from 1  to 2,  2   to 3,and  same   as   upto  10

if i go to 5  th view,then  i  press home  button   and   then i  go   to another application and  then after   doing   some  task  ,i  go  to home  button  and   then   i   press my  application my 1 st   view   opens   but   i  want   to    open   my 5   th   view

plzzzzzzzzz    tell   me    solution    for   this
waiting   fo  reply

Answer (score 1):

What I do is put an integer in NSUserDefaults for the key `@"navigationDepth"` with how deep it is, and any other information such as the index of the item being edited. Then when the app launches, the app delegate sends a message to view controllers to push the appropriate number of view controllers. Here's some sample code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Restore navigation depth and picture being viewed or edited
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id root = [navigationController topViewController];
    int navDepth = [defaults integerForKey:@"navDepth"];
    int pictureIndex = [defaults integerForKey:@"currentPictureIndex"];
    switch (navDepth) {
        case 1:
            [root viewImageAtIndex:pictureIndex animated:NO];
            break;
        case 2:
            [root editImageAtIndex:pictureIndex animated:NO];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the code for pushing view controllers:

```
- (void) viewImageAtIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ((0 <= index) && (index < allPictures.count)) {
        ViewerViewController *c = [[ViewerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewerViewController"];
        c.allPictures = self.allPictures;
        c.currentPictureIndex = index;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:animated];
        [c release];
    }
}

- (void) editImageAtIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated {
    ViewerViewController *c = [[ViewerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewerViewController"]; 
    c.allPictures = self.allPictures;
    c.currentPictureIndex = index;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:NO];
    [c editPictureWithAnimation:animated]; // Immediately push the editor view controller
    [c release];
}
```

Comment: [root viewImageAtIndex:pictureIndex animated:NO];
what  this line will do?

Comment: In his case, it probably steps through the navigation hierarchy to the appropriate view controller corresponding with being one level deep in that hierarchy.

Comment: It pushes a view controller. I've edited my answer to add the code which does that. Hope this helps.